# Java - get annotation is always null

Tags: java, annotations

I am new to annotations, i have classes annotated with custom annotation `FXMLController`, send these classes to a factory to get the value from the annotation, but it is always null ~

annotation :

```
public @interface FXMLController {

    String value() default "";

}
```

usage :

```
@FXMLController(value=CommonConstants.SPLASH_SCREEN)
public class SplashScreenController{ ....... )
```

getting the value :

```
Annotation annotation = controller.getAnnotation(FXMLController.class);
FXMLController fxmlController = (FXMLController) annotation;
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that you forgot to mark your annotation as `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

EDIT:
In fact your annotation should look like:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documentedpublic @interface FXMLController {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i think that i have to read more about annotations